# What does registerServiceWorker do in React JS?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, service-worker, react-dom

I'm a newbie in React and I was wondering what is the purpose of registerServiceWorker() in the following code?

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import App from './App';
import registerServiceWorker from './registerServiceWorker';

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById('root'));
registerServiceWorker();
```

Answer (score 126, accepted):

The service worker is a web API that helps you cache your assets and other files so that when the user is offline or on slow network, he/she can still see results on the screen, as such, it helps you build a better user experience, that's what you should know about service worker's for now. It's all about adding offline capabilities to your site.

React creates a service worker for you without your configuration by default. To learn more;

- [Service Workers, MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Service_Worker_API)
- [Service Workers, Google Web Fundamentals](https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/primers/service-workers/)
- [Simple offline site using service worker, CSS Tricks](https://css-tricks.com/serviceworker-for-offline/)
- [Server worker: A case study, Smashing Magazine](https://www.smashingmagazine.com/2016/02/making-a-service-worker/)

Comment: Is it only for dev env or it can be carried away for prod also?

Comment: Its by default for production 
https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app/blob/master/packages/react-scripts/template/README.md#making-a-progressive-web-app

Answer (score 1):

The service worker is to use the website data offline in case there is no network, it's like making PWA. Refer to this link [PWA](https://facebook.github.io/create-react-app/docs/making-a-progressive-web-app) to know more about implementation and how to use registerServiceWorker().