# Within React is registerServiceWorker.js Required?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

As a newbie to React I'd like to know if **registerServiceWorker.js** is required.

I ask because I noticed (after spending countless hours looking) that it conflicts with what is being rendered on my DOM. Within my dev environment everything works. In production though things aren't as rosey. However, if I remove `registerServiceWorker()` then everything works in production.

Based on [someone else's question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47953732/what-does-registerserviceworker-do-in-react-js) I understand that it helps cache my assets.

Comment: service workers are used to improve your app's performance for repeated users, users with low connectivity, etc. If you do not want it - you can just comment out the line inside `index.js` where the service worker is registered - as simple as that :)

Comment: i'll move forward with your advice and leave it commented out.

Answer (score 1):

I imagine you're using create-react-app? As far as I'm aware, it is required for now, but they are moving away from it, as per Dan Abranov's [twitter](https://twitter.com/dan_abramov/status/954146978564395008).

Comment: you are correct. i am using create-react-app. sounds like service workers are still a bit buggy.

Answer (score 1):

They are definitely optional!

If you comment out `registerServiceWorker()` or remove it entirely from index.js it won't be included and you'll have a standard web app.

This means that you won't get the progressive enhancement--meaning (simply put) that your app will throw 500's in offline mode and will overall be a tad less snappy. Generally speaking turning it on is not great practice until the project you're working on is relatively stable as it caches assets so changes aren't always noticed immediately by users after a deploy

If you want to read up on the whole discourse of it being a default in create-react-app it was slightly controversial: 
https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app/issues/2398